# how to modify style.css in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, styles

**Magento ver. 2.2.0-dev**

I want to make changes in style.css which is located at **"pub/static/frontend/mytheme/mytheme_default/en_US/css/style.css"**.

If I make any changes in this folder directly no changes are taken place.

There is a file style.less in **/app/design/frontend/theme/theme2/web/css**

*Update:*
i created a file style.css in  `/app/design/frontend/theme/theme2/web/css/style.css`

and called the same class as defined in `"pub/static/frontend/mytheme/mytheme_default/en_US/css/style.css"**`

with some changes and run 
**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** from putty still it caches old styles.

then flushed cache also

```
Flushed cache types:
config
layout
block_html
collections
reflection
db_ddl
eav
customer_notification
config_integration
config_integration_api
full_page
translate
config_webservice
```

**Update:**

CSS is not merged from admin panel.

**I commented old pub and run deploy - f, still CSS not updated and all the images are not showing. In the console, they are showing 404 for all images.**

image path 
http://website.in/pub/media/Plazathemes/brandslider/images/2/_/2_2.png
what to do.

Any suggestions.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change in **style.less** or **style.css** in your theme folder and then deploy content as follows.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

You need to run above command from Magento 2 root directory.

Comment: There is no style.css in my theme , so I must change in style.less or I should make a style.css and make changes to those classes which I want

Comment: Yes. You can do the same.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, still, css is not updating.

Comment: I am accepting your solution as i make changes in style.less file and then deployed , style.css in pub is updated. My problem is solved `but , is it necessary to write in less always because if i create .css in same folder and then deploy nothing happens.`